# Add catalina-ant.jar in Jenkin's classpath

Tags: tomcat, ant, jenkins, hudson, catalina

I want to add catalina-ant.jar in Jenkins' classpath to be able to use task definitions in my ant script like :

```
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask" />
```

I've deployed the jenkins war file in Tomcat. How do I add it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing to do is to add this jar the ANT distribution configured within Jenkins:

```
$ANT_HOME/lib
```

Or alternatively under the jenkins home directory as follows:

```
$HOME/.ant/lib
```

On Debian that would be:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.ant/lib
```